# Device driver to capture wireless traffic using Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: drivers, wifi

I wish to be able to read wireless traffic sent from my wireless keyboard. At first I thought I could just buy some board like Arduino, plug in a module like nRF24L01+ and use this combo.

Since I'm not good at all with electronics I'd rather find another solution and, eventually, I thought that I already have a transreceiver for wireless comunication: my laptop Wi-Fi adapter.

As I said, I don't know much about electronics, so I wonder if it's actually possible to write a linux device driver for my adapter in order to make it able to capture and process wireless communication other than Wi-Fi.

Is this doable? Is this the best route I can follow, rather than using an Arduino with a wireless module?

**EDIT**
I'm not looking for an implementation of such a device driver, my goal is to write it myself. I'm just asking if there is something I'm not taking into consideration before starting this journey.

Answer (score 2):

Not a device driver, but rather an informative PDF of things that you will need to know to pull off this exploit:
http://www.remote-exploit.org/content/keykeriki_v2_cansec_v1.1.pdf

You will see that the exploit is not so easy to pull off, but then again certainly within the realm of possibility for a targeted attack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm gonna check this out! Just to make it clear: I'm not looking for an implementation of such a device driver, my goal is to write it myself. I'm just asking if there is something I'm not taking into consideration before starting this journey.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm trying to do myself but they are using custom hardware which I'd like to avoid in favour of using my wireless adapter.

Comment: I see. I figured that the techniques would help no matter which hardware.